# spyder crash itertools.combinations

Tags: python, spyder, combinatorics

I have this program:

import itertools
import random

```
randomlist = []
for i in range(0,32):
    a = random.randint(1,30)
    randomlist.append(a)
    print(randomlist)

a = randomlist
all_combinations = []
min_num_of_funds = 4 
max_num_of_funds = 10
for i in range(0,len(a)+1):
    if i>=min_num_of_funds & i<=max_num_of_funds:
        comb = list(itertools.combinations(a,i))
        all_combinations.append(comb)
```

I get the following error

Kernel died, restarting

```
Restarting kernel... 


 Populating the interactive namespace from numpy and matplotlib

[SpyderKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm: 4b233da0a85511ebb62bacde48001122
[SpyderKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm: 48c21daea86b11ebb62bacde48001122
[SpyderKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm: 61748e76a86c11ebb62bacde48001122
[SpyderKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm: fd9fd78ca86d11ebb62bacde48001122


Kernel died, restarting
```

My feeling is that the source of the problem is the list `a' might relatively large. Any suggestions in getting around the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `&` in boolean expressions.  Use `and`.  They aren't the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll want to use `and` instead of `&` (bitwise and operator in python).

You're running out of memory because large values of `i` will still be evaluating to `True`:

```
i = 100

i >= 4 & i <= 10
Out[33]: True
```

```
sys.getsizeof(list(itertools.combinations(list(range(32)), 10)))
Out[29]: 572759960 (~572 MB)
```

That's already getting up there in memory but because of that error your program is evaluating even larger values of `i` and it's causing Spyder to run out of memory.

Suggest the following (which works for me without running out of memory):

```
randomlist = []
for i in range(0,32):
    a = random.randint(1,30)
    randomlist.append(a)
    print(randomlist)

a = randomlist
all_combinations = []
min_num_of_funds = 4 
max_num_of_funds = 10
for i in range(min_num_of_funds, max_num_of_funds+1):
    comb = list(itertools.combinations(a,i))
    all_combinations.append(comb)
```